# map two lists together in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

I have two facts which are x(a, b, c) and g(x, y, z).

I want to create a rule to print all possible answers such that if I pick one member from the first fact and match it with a member from the second fact then I can't match another member from the first fact to the same member in the second fact that was matched before, for ex. [a,x], [b, x] are not acceptable.

```
... X = [[a,x],[b,y],[c,z]]

... X = [[a,y],[b,z],[c,x]]

... X = [[a,z],[b,x],[c,y]]

.
.
.
```

you get the point I hope, there should be 9 I think.

Comment: mylinks([[a,e],[b,d],[c,f]]).

colors2([red, blue, green]).
getCol([],[], Y , Y).
getCol([],[],[],Z):- mylinks([[A|[B|_]]|T]), colors2([C|T2]),
 getCol(T,T2, [[A|[C]]|[[B|[C]]]],Z).

Comment: That, which prints one answer only.

Comment: Please don't put your code in a comment. Edit your question and add it there, properly formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think that there should be 9 in your sample? There should be exactly 6:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

?- maplist(\K^V^KV^(KV = K-V), [a,b,c], Rs, LRs), permutation([x,y,z], Rs).
   Rs = [x,y,z], LRs = [a-x,b-y,c-z]
;  Rs = [x,z,y], LRs = [a-x,b-z,c-y]
;  Rs = [y,x,z], LRs = [a-y,b-x,c-z]
;  Rs = [y,z,x], LRs = [a-y,b-z,c-x]
;  Rs = [z,x,y], LRs = [a-z,b-x,c-y]
;  Rs = [z,y,x], LRs = [a-z,b-y,c-x]
;  false.
```

Comment: why only 6? if we have x(a, b, c) and g(x, y, z) then we should have: [(ax)(by)(cz)] , [(ay)(bz)(cx)] , [(az)(bx)(cy)] and so on?

Comment: @JosephMaanAnayee. Be more specific... Instead of using the phrase "and so on", please *write down all solutions you expect* explicitly!

Comment: @JosephMaanAnayee: All cases you gave are present!